# Hide "web" from URL in Symfony2.8 application

Tags: php, symfony

I have two different Symfony2.8 applications. During development they are accessible via two separated domains (virtual hosts): `www.app1.local` and `www.app2.local`. And everything works fine. But finally both applications should be deployed to the one server with one domain. Therefore I created two folders for each application.

Document root is `/httpdocs`, so file `/httpdocs/test.php` is accessible via `www.domain.com/test.php`. Two folders are `/httpdocs/app1` and `/httpdocs/app2`. Each contains different installation of Symfony2.8 with own bundles etc.

And what is the problem? The `web` in URL. The URL to application looks like `www.domain.com/app1/web/index.php` instead of `www.domain.com/app2/web/index.php`. I'm trying to hide this `web` from URL but I don't have idea how to do this.

Comment: "The Web Directory" here explain how to do that on different web servers http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html

Comment: and here how override the web directory if needed http://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/override_dir_structure.html#override-the-web-directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, it should be configurated via web-server itself. But if you don't have any access to configuration of web-server (Apache, nginx), you can do the following.

Put in your `/httpdocs/app1` copy of `app1/web`, and in `/httpdocs/app2` copy of `app1/web`

Applications themselves put in some other place.
So it will look, for example, like this:

```
app1/
  app/
  bin/
  ... # <--no web among these folders
  composer.json
  ...
app2/
  app/
  bin/
  ... # <--no web among these folders
  composer.json
  ...
httpdocs/
  app1/
    bundles/
    ....
    index.php
  app2/
    bundles/
    ....
    index.php
```

And then in your `index.php` fix paths to application

```
  $loader = require __DIR__.'/../../app1/app/autoload.php';
  include_once __DIR__.'/../../app1/var/bootstrap.php.cache';
```

(and same for app2, but with `app2`).

Also, fix both `composer.json`

```
"symfony-web-dir": "../httpdocs/app1",
```